# overrides nimbus properties

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, uimanager

I'm trying to overrides some of the nimbus properties for JLabel.

```
UIDefaults labelDefault = new UIDefaults();
    labelDefault.put("Label.font", new FontUIResource("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    labelDefault.put("Label.foreground", new ColorUIResource(210, 210, 210));
label.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", labelDefault);
    label.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false);
```

For the font it works correctly, but not for the color.  Is it possible to change the color this way ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
labelDefault.put("Label[Enabled].textForeground", new ColorUIResource(210, 210, 210));
```